# Question about matlab mex-file memory

Tags: matlab, memory, mex

Hey there,
assuming I have the following code in a mex routine:

```
mxArray *newPoint = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
double *newPointData = mxGetPr(newPoint);
newPoint = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[1]);
```

do I have than to update newPointData also again to point to the new mxArray? And what about the memory where the first occurance of `newPoint` points to? Do I than also need to destroy that via `mxDestroyArray(newPoint);` because if I don't do it, I'll loose the address to it after re-assigning `newPoint`.

Thanks!

Edit: Bump on this please for a better understanding of memory allocation problem!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mxDuplicateArray` allocates a new array and copies the data. Each new duplicated array will have its data stored in a different memory region.

So, yes, you have to use `mxGetPr()` to get the address of the data after each call to `mxDuplicateArray()`.

And naturally, allocated arrays must be deallocated. For that, you need to keep the original pointer to each mxArray created (the one returned by `mxDuplicateArray`).

Finally, you *cannot* destroy the `mxArray` after taking the address of the data (using mxGetPr). Otherwise you are accessing memory which has been deallocated and may be allocated again by other code for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that `mxDuplicateArray` doesn't do the deep-copy in some cases:
http://jp.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/310346

Bug is not fixed, and documentation on the function is still wrong.